# How do we reference an already opened instance of quick test?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

How do we reference an already opened instance of quick test application (QTP) for e.g we will use Set monDocument = GetObject("c:\report.doc") to refer an already opened MS Word file saved in c:\report.doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the QTP automation object

```
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
```

If it's already open you'll get the existing instance, otherwise you will have to launch it.

```
If  Not qtApp.launched Then 
    qtApp.Launch 
End If
```

Code stolen from [here](http://www.qtpworld.com/index.php?cid=77).